# HTML/CSS Buttons issue

Tags: html, css, button

I've been recently using HTML to create a program for a school project. Everything went fairly well, until now. Any buttons or text I place in seem to be blocked by a barrier, but I don't know what.

I have a JSFiddle link, but for the actual program I am using  Adobe Edge-Code
http://jsfiddle.net/nwsuoarw/1/
The issue is with the

`<button id="b4">Leave</button>`
and
`<button id="b5">Newspaper</button>`

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT: I worded this question extremely poorly, and for that I apologise. What I meant was that I could't place the buttons inside the main box. Or as it it known in the code

```
<div class="one">
```

Comment: copy paste the code of script.js in fiddler js  javascript portion

Comment: What do you mean by "a barrier?" In the JSFiddle you provide, it's true that you can't click on 'Tour' or similar buttons, but you *are* able to click successfully on "Honey" and "Beeswax," so I would guess that it's something to do with the positioning of these buttons. Perhaps with the z-index of the items?

Comment: The bottom edge of the main rectangle is acting like a barrier for "Newspaper" and "Leave" I haven't been able to make them go above that line. And yeah, I'v only coded two buttons, just to make sure they worked, but I want to put these two in the right place before I code any more.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by you can't place buttons in <div class="one">. All of the code is in <div class="one"> in the jsfiddle you have linked.

Comment: What I mean is that No matter what i have tried, the "Newspaper" and "Leave" buttons won't physically go into the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with CSS for DIV 8... If you remove that CSS newspaper clicks fine. You have couple of options.

- Tweak the CSS for Div 8 - Would say delete it...(if you cannot do it then)
- Put the newspaper button outside the div 8.

Love button is clicking fine in the fiddle you provided.

```
Code is below in fiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nwsuoarw/4/

Comment: See, the only problem Is, when I try to put the "Newspaper" button inside the black box at the top, it moves to the bottom of the page.

Comment: And this one has both buttons inside the box. They are also clickable... http://jsfiddle.net/nwsuoarw/9/ (I would highly recommend that you visit your CSS styling and script code.) What you want to write can be done with very clean html.

Comment: Thank you so much spooky! That last one allowed me to see what I did wrong. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**working code Demo**

```
http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/nwsuoarw/2/
```

Issue is problem was with the script file you included to jsfiddle 
**html**

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three">
        <p id="p1">Honey</p>
        <button id="b1", onclick="myFunction()">Buy</button>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
            var area = Number(prompt("How many pounds of Honey would you like? ($0.39 per pound)"));
            var answer = (area * 0.39);
            confirm("$" + answer);
            } 
        </script>               
    </div>
    <div class="four">
        <p id="p2">Beeswax</p>
        <button id="b2"onclick="myFunction()">Buy</button>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
            var area = Number(prompt("How many pounds of Beeswax would you like? ($0.39 per pound)"));
            var answer = (area * 0.39);
            confirm("$" + answer);
            } 
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="five">
        <button id="b3">Tour</button> 
    </div>
    <div class="face">
        <button>Help</button>
    </div>
    <div class="six">
    </div>
    <div class="seven">
    </div> 
    <div class="eight">
        <button id="b5">Newspaper</button>
    </div>
    <button id="b4">Leave</button>
</div>
<h1 id="h1">Welcome to Maycomb Honeycomb!</h1>
<h3>This is our virtual tour v1.0! Enjoy!<h3>
```

Comment: The problem he is describing is still there. Try to click on "Newspaper", you can't.

Comment: nothing is written for newspaper <button id="b5">Newspaper</button> i mean for those he need to write his logic or redirect to appropriate page

Comment: You're right the button doesn't do anything but you should still be able to see a button click animation when pressing on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your missing the on click event and the function inside the script.  If thats the case then see below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>

<div class="one">
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three">
        <p id="p1">Honey</p>
        <button id="b1", onclick="myFunction();">Buy</button>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
            var area = Number(prompt("How many pounds of Honey would you like? ($0.39 per pound)"));
            var answer = (area * 0.39);
            confirm("$" + answer);
            } 
function leave(){
// your code goes here;
}
function Newspaper(){
// your code goes here;
}
        </script>               
    </div>
    <div class="four">
        <p id="p2">Beeswax</p>
        <button id="b2"onclick="myFunction()">Buy</button>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
            var area = Number(prompt("How many pounds of Beeswax would you like? ($0.39 per pound)"));
            var answer = (area * 0.39);
            confirm("$" + answer);
            } 
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="five">
        <button id="b3">Tour</button> 
    </div>
    <div class="face">
        <button>Help</button>
    </div>
    <div class="six">
    </div>
    <div class="seven">
    </div> 
    <div class="eight">
        <button id="b5"onclick="Newspaper();">Newspaper</button>
    </div>
    <button id="b4" onclick="leave();">Leave</button>
</div>
<h1 id="h1">Welcome to Maycomb Honeycomb!</h1>
<h3>This is our virtual tour v1.0! Enjoy!<h3>
```

Comment: The div tag is preventing him from the animation when his mouse hovers over the button, so removing the buttons from inside the <div class="five"> and <div class="face"> <div class="eight">, will bring back his mouse hover animations.